# onBindViewHolder .get(position) gets position on null object reference

Tags: android, android-studio, android-recyclerview, android-adapter

On the method onBindViewHolder I get an error that I am calling .get(position) on a null reference object.

No idea how to fix this.

```
 @Override
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull ViewHolder holder, int 
 position) {

    String desc_data = event_list.get(position).getDesc();

    holder.setDescText(desc_data);


 }
```

This is an Error I got in the LogCat.
`

```
2019-09-09 19:16:30.479 14504-14504/com.example.iacs E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.iacs, PID: 14504
    java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke interface method 'java.lang.Object java.util.List.get(int)' on a null object reference
        at com.example.iacs.EventRecyclerAdapter.onBindViewHolder(EventRecyclerAdapter.java:38)
        at com.example.iacs.EventRecyclerAdapter.onBindViewHolder(EventRecyclerAdapter.java:13)
        at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView$Adapter.onBindViewHolder(RecyclerView.java:6781)
        at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView$Adapter.bindViewHolder(RecyclerView.java:6823)
        at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.tryBindViewHolderByDeadline(RecyclerView.java:5752)
        at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.tryGetViewHolderForPositionByDeadline(RecyclerView.java:6019)
        at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.getViewForPosition(RecyclerView.java:5858)

        `
```

Comment: Is your `event_list` initialized?

Comment: `
    public List<EventPost> event_list;

    public EventRecyclerAdapter(List<EventPost> event_list){

        this.event_list = event_list;

    }
`
I believe so

Comment: Are you sure none of the items inside the list are null? Inside the constructor and run a `for` loop and print out all the items. Check if any of them are null.

Comment: It probably is, because I ran for loop and got the same null reference object error. Not sure where I made the mistake, as the event_list is from the firebase collection I've made previously

Comment: It's not an item in the `List`. It's the `List` itself that is null. You've not provided enough information for us to be able to tell you why that is, exactly.

Answer (score 0):

write this check

```
if(event_list != null && event_list.size >= position ){
String desc_data = event_list.get(position).getDesc();
holder.setDescText(desc_data+"");
}
```

I hope this check resolve your null point exception

Comment: the app still keeps crashing

Comment: just shared it.

Comment: String desc_data = event_list.get(position).getDesc() + "" ;  just do that its solve your problem